# Android AutoCompleteTextView For URL addresses

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a problem with Android. When you are using AutoCompleteTextView :

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.entry);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.url_addresses);

String[] url_addresses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url_addresses);
for (String string : url_addresses) {
    adapter.add(string);
}

textView.setAdapter(adapter);
.....
```

And when you entered the "google" keyword in textbox, auto complete system showing all urls  which is start with "google".
For example:

- google.com
- google.com.tr
- google.co.uk

But, I want to show urls which is contains "google".
For example:

- http://www.google.com/
- https://mail.google.com/
- http://another.google.com/

I think this problem occurred if item does not contains any space (one word, like url).

It is possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple. Wrap the url string into another class and in `toString` return the url with dots replaced with spaces. For example, The url `http://mail.google.com` will be returned as `http://mail google com` which will be matched easily by the filter. You can replace other characters also  similarly before returning the string seperated by spaces. Like `//`

```
class urlString {

   String url;
   public String toString() {
       return url.replace('.',' ');// replace dots with space
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It can be a good idea. But URL list would be complicated. If I make a URL address changes, the list will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Write your own adapter instead of using the base ArrayAdapter. See the Filter.performFiltering... [Android AutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter filtering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784249/android-autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working)