# AutoCompleteText issue getting repeated values in list?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

[image]

Please help me out with this issue:

I want to display country and code when i search in the autocomplete text view and its working  fine but iam getting twice values rather than single value.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] countries = new String[] {
                "Allentown",
            "Albuquerque","Aberdeen","Acapulco","Waco","Atlantic City",
            "Marka-Amman","Pittsburgh","Augusta","Auckland","Albany",
            "Amarillo","Amman","Amsterdam","Anchorage","Antwerp",
            "Naples","Aqaba","Stockholm","Aspen","Asuncion"......};

    String[] codes=new String[]{
        "ABE","ABQ","AMS","ANC","ANR","APF","AQJ","ARN","ASE","ASU","ATH",
    .............}; 
    List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        curGroupMap.put("country", countries[i]);
        curGroupMap.put("code", codes[i]);
        list.add(curGroupMap);
    }
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = 
            new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), list, R.layout.twolist, new String[] {"code","country"}, new int[] { R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2});
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View v, int pos, long id) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) p.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            String itemName = map.get("code");
            textView.setText(itemName);
        }
    });
 }

}
```

#### And my xml for getting the listview is **twolist.xml:**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/a"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="-" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
                   list, R.layout.twolist,
                   new String[] {"code","country"},
                   new int[] { R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2});
```

Here you are using:

```
R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2
```

So it will display it in both `Textview`s.

Comment: yeah @Arju but im displaying the code and country as well in the list to appear when i search in textbox and i tried with textview1 also by not giving the other textview, in that case it appends only code but not country.so can u pls check the image above and solve it.

Comment: @Danny its a hell prob iam trying it step by step

Comment: I gave you a downvote just for that horrible formatting.

Comment: @AbAppletic  Theres only a line of code and it is readable. Edited for formatting ?

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan I edited it for formatting, but your effort in making it READABLE (No, it wasn't readable at all) deserved that downvote. I have no intention of discussing this futher with you.

Comment: Oh and not only the formatting was bad, but also you were too lazy to even type in "you" right. (*"u"? Seriously? **We're not on Instagram, we're on a programmer's Q&A site***)

Comment: OP got what I said. What's wrong with you ? Finding mistakes give you satisfaction ? **SERIOUSLY** ?

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in you implementation for removing duplication item in list

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    curGroupMap.put("country", countries[i]);
    curGroupMap.put("code", codes[i]);
    list.add(curGroupMap);
}

// adde elements to list, including duplicates
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: updated the above code but still now iam getting the duplicate values the issue is not fixed :( @Pratik

Comment: Hi @Danny check out this post answer you need to filter using custom adapter http://stackoverflow.com/a/8784931/760489

Comment: yeah but is there any method are API to display only distinct values of which it should not get repeated values and can u post the simple logic @Pratik

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, But simple answer for this problem is that your List that you populate through adapter in the AutoCompleteTextView, contains duplicates.  Because AutoComplete will always populate only unique Data.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: I met up with this condition, so i manage to have only unique values in my List. so that your AutoCompleteTextView wont display any duplicates.