# AutoCompleteTextView - Suggestions auto-close when `notifyDataSetChanged` called

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I created adapter and created filter. The adapter works fine but every time when I'm calling to notifyDataSetChanged the dropdown list of the AutoCompleteTextView closed and then reopens again with new suggestions.

Is there any way to avoid this closing and re-opening of the dropdown?

**EDIT**

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static final Filter NO_FILTER = new NoFilter();

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public void updateList(String prefix) {
        List<String> list = ...; //from web server;

        clear();
        foreach (String s : list)
            add(s);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return NO_FILTER;
    }


    private static class NoFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            return new FilterResults();
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you call notifyDataSetChanged in adaper?

Comment: Yes, I call notifyDataSetChanged inside the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use notifyDataSetChanged() in method publishResults(..)

for example:

[Android AutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter filtering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784249/android-autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working)

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-adapter-for-autocomplete.aspx