# Error using notifyDataSetChanged in android array adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

> 11-06 19:52:25.958: E/AndroidRuntime(29609):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(-1, class
>   android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with Adapter(class
>   com.example.parkfoxxlight_android.PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter)]

Full log: http://pastebin.com/Hx7k28Rm

Full code of adapter: http://pastebin.com/TfH1bXE3 I am using the example from https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android and it has quite the default code so it seems there is a bug in the google code?

The app crashes only sometimes with the above error message.

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
        FilterResults results) {

    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

Activity http://pastebin.com/FYzYtvXY:

```
public class CityActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.city);

            AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_city);

            PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter ad = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this);
            ProgressBar b = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            ad.setLoadingIndicator(b);

            autoCompView.setAdapter(ad);
        }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I am on android 4.3.

Comment: What line of code is it crashing on? By the way, you are casting Context to Activity which is unsafe and will definitely cause crashes in some circumstances. I think you can replace `act.runOnUiThread` with `mHandler.post`, and create your Handler in the constructor.

Comment: Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/Hx7k28Rm

Comment: @Tenfour04 activity and context, isn't it the same?

Comment: They are not, otherwise you wouldn't have to cast. Activity is a subclass of context, so if someone tries to instantiate your adapter using `new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getBaseContext())` (for example), they will get a ClassCastException when the filter runs.

Comment: The `Filter`'s `performFiltering()` method runs on a background thread and from that method you're changing the `resultList` on which your adapter is based. If you change that list and in that time the `ListView` access the adapter it will see that something has changed without its knowledge(and it will not be happy). Check this piece of code https://gist.github.com/luksprog/7382576 .

Comment: @Luksprog I refactored my code based on your comment and the problem disappeared. You can post this as a question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `Filter`'s `performFiltering()` method runs on a background thread and from that method you're changing the `resultList` on which your adapter is based. If you change that list of data and in that time the `ListView` access the adapter it will see that something has changed without its knowledge(and it will not be happy). You should avoid using the `resultList` in the `performFiltering` method and simply create a new temporary list:

```
// in the performFiltering method which runs on a background thread:
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
     FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
     ArrayList<String> queryResults;
     if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
         queryResults = autocomplete(constraint);
     } else {
         queryResults = new ArrayList<String>(); // empty list/no suggestions showing if there's no valid constraint
     }
     filterResults.values = queryResults;
     filterResults.count = queryResults.size();
     return filterResults; // ## Heading ##
}

private List<String> autocomplete(String input) {
   // don't use the here the resultList List on which the adapter is based!
   // some custom code to get items from http connection
     ArrayList<String> queryResults = new ArrayList<String>(); // new list
     queryResults.add("Some String");
     return queryResults;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
     // update the data with the new set of suggestions
     resultList = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
     if (results.count > 0) {
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     } else {
         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
     }
}
```

Comment: excellent guys! very very veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy helpful. Incredible ......

Comment: @Luksprog.. sorry to bother and not trying to hijack  this thread but could you take a look at this post.. its based on your solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568337/autocompletetextview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-chang

Comment: The line `if (constraint != null || constraint.length() == 0) {` will cause a NPE, when constraint equals null.   The if block should only check for constraint!=null

Comment: @luksprog short circuiting is the culprit here.   when constraint is null,  `constraint != null` becomes false,  then the or operator will try to evaluate the constraint.length()==0, thereby causing the NPE.    What we need is `if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)`. Now short circuiting will protect against NPE

Comment: @PurushothamanRamraj Yeah, I've seen it now, at that time I stupidly  mixed the two constraint conditions(not being null and not being empty). Good find, I wonder why nobody bothered to comment on this all this time.

Comment: I am having same problem can any one look into my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034523/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just a guess):

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    ArrayList list = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                    if (list != null) {
                        filterResults.values = list;
                        filterResults.count = list.size();
                    }
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    //change the underlying data immediately before notifying UI                        
                    resultList = (ArrayList)results.values; 
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: results.values has to be cast to (ArrayList<String>)? Tried it and autocomplete is not working anymore

Comment: Filter.publishResults is performed on the ui thread automatically. I really cannot imagine why I get this error