# How can i make a email AutocompleteTextview

Tags: android

I want to make a autocomplete in an activity form..(email case) I want to activate the autocompleteTextView when the user press (@) like .. widy@ and the autocomplete activate just like (@gmail.com,@hotmail.com,etc..).. please how can I do this?

```
String[] email = {"@gmail.com", "@hotmail.com", "@yahoo.com"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,email);


AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto);
actv.setThreshold(1);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried this code but it's only activated when the @ is the first character.

Comment: this is your answer. :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132909/autocompletetextview-with-email-domains-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoCompleteTextView with email domains android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132909/autocompletetextview-with-email-domains-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library I developed.

[EmailAutoCompleteTextView](https://github.com/oguzhandongul/EmailAutoCompleteTextView)

Usage is really simple:

```
<com.oguzhandongul.library.EmailAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
    android:entries="@array/domains"/>
```

You can set mail domains array via **XML** or **Java**.

Just check the [Sample App](https://github.com/oguzhandongul/EmailAutoCompleteTextView/tree/master/app/src/main)

You can copy files(`EmailAutoCompleteTextView.java` and `attrs.xml`) to your project easily.