# make custom filter for autocompletetextview android

Tags: android, filter, autocompletetextview

hi my task is simple that make a `autocompletetextview` and show matched text in `dropdown`. But i want to change in filter.

Ex: my `list` is like `D.Y.Patil College`,`Pune unversiry` etc. I want that when user type `dy` or `dyp` it stat matching and display result.

How could i ignore `whitespace` and dot.

And also Could u plz tell me to how exactly `autocompletetextview`  works.

Comment: Are you using any third party lib for autocompletetextview

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784249/android-autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working

Comment: @Nithinlal no I

Comment: AutoCompleteView is simple to understand .You can refer this https://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example.

Comment: @VikasTiwari where should i use this code. I mean in my `editProfile.java` or `autocompletetextview.java` or `filter.java`

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) for a  simple solution for a custom filter

Comment: Could anyone explain more about my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using by default adapter and filter, `autocompletetextview` can do only single line string in dropdown view as default adapter and default filter `adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());` which can do filtering with condition of `inputString.contains(stringOfList)` one-bye-one and get and display that list in dropdown at autocompletextview.

There for you have to make simple `custom adapter` and `inside that custom filter class` for filtering as per your requirement.

Comment: `autocompletetextview` does not have any "default adapter" nor "default filter" - always you have to call `setAdapter` for `ACTV` to work

Comment: @pskink have any idea to make custom adpter....I tried but need some deep information

Comment: @BabluGaur i already sent you a link with a custom filtering (an hour ago)

Comment: @pskink thnkx i understand the concept

Comment: @pskink I apologies if i misguide the concept or any word and if possible please edit that. Thanks for that.