# How can I implement a custom autocomplete dictionary for non standard text input?

Tags: android, multilingual

I'm re-writing part of [a larger GTK/Python program](http://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/) to [Android](http://github.com/Ghini/ghini.pocket).  In one of the edit texts, my users will be typing a botanic taxon name, things that include words like *Pachypharynx* or *Erythroxylaceae*.

Such words are part of a "Botanic lexicon", and people who speak different languages pronounce them differently, and make different typing mistakes when entering them.  Some have quasi-homonyms, like the /Hieronima/Hyeronima/Hieronyma/ group, where the first two are classified as Euphorbiaceae, the latter as Phyllanthaceae.  Some are valid names but a better choice is available (eg: Coccus is considered a synonym of Cocos)

So where's the programming problem?  Well, I want to help the user!

- I need a `TextView`,
- in this `TextView`, I need to help the user type the name,
- I can't dirty the user's dictionary with botanic names,
- allow for possible typing mistakes, but prefer literal matching,
- give context information (the family name),
- help the user prefer accepted epithets.

I have considered and discarded the following:

- define your own input method, (overkill)
- alter the user dictionary, (unacceptable)

I would like to

- use an `AutoCompleteTextView` (but how?)

and I consider this question worth being asked (I don't know why you guys/ladies downvote without explanation) and I think that the answer I found and built is going to help others.

Comment: Simply use a database.

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds on others, but most of all on [Carl Anderson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769564/78912).  It is based on AutoCompleteTextView option, and I am going to look one by one at each element of the solution.

First of all, when creating the view, let's grab the ACTV and associate it with a custom adapter:

```
public View onCreateView([...]) {
 .
 .
    TaxonomyDatabase db = new TaxonomyDatabase(getContext());
    List<Epithet> allEpithets = db.getAllGenera();
    EpithetAdapter hints = new EpithetAdapter(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, allEpithets);
    AutoCompleteTextView widget = rootView.findViewById(R.id.etCollectSpecies);
    widget.setThreshold(2); // start hinting from second character
    widget.setAdapter(hints);
```

The `TaxonomyDatabase.getAllGenera` grabs all genera from the database, with their accepted equivalent, and the family they belong to.

```
List<Epithet> getAllGenera() {
    ArrayList<Epithet> r = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(
            "select o.epithet, a.epithet, o.phonetic, a.family_name " +
                    "from taxon o "+"" +
                    "left join taxon a on o.accepted_id = a.id " +
                    "where o.rank = 5 " +
                    "order by o.epithet",
            new String[]{});
     .
     .
```

Now the EpithetAdapter constructor accepts this list, and first adds it to its internal candidates list, but then again copies each Epithet again in the list: the first instance is for literal match, the second instance is to allow for phonetic match.  The logic of this is hidden in Epithet copy constructor, that sets the `isExact` field to `false`.

```
EpithetAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Epithet> epithets) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, epithets);
    // copy all the epithets twice
    mEpithets = new ArrayList<>(epithets.size() * 2);
    // first to be used as exact matches (String×4 constructor)
    mEpithets.addAll(epithets);
    // then again to be used as phonetic matches (copy constructor)
    for(Epithet e : epithets) {
        mEpithets.add(new Epithet(e));
    }
}
```

The Epithet class has a toString method, that takes care of how the Epithet shows in the ACTV drop down list:

```
public String toString() {
    if (accepted != null) {
        return epithet + " → " + accepted;
    } else {
        return epithet + " (" + family + ")";
    }
}
```

the Filter in the EpithetAdapter does the rest of the task: when user clicks on a suggestion, `ConvertResultToString` is invoked:

```
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        return ((Epithet)resultValue).epithet;
    }
```

Filtering itself, that is the `performFiltering` method, is just the logical consequence of all said up to now:

```
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null) {
            String exact = constraint.toString();
            String phonetic = TaxonomyDatabase.phonetic(exact);
            exact = exact.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + exact.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<Epithet> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Epithet epithet : mEpithets) {
                if (epithet.isExact) {
                    if (epithet.epithet.startsWith(exact)) {
                        suggestions.add(epithet);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (epithet.phonetic.startsWith(phonetic) &&
                            !epithet.epithet.startsWith(exact)) {
                        suggestions.add(epithet);
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = suggestions;
            results.count = suggestions.size();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

- last minor detail, disable text suggestions (`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` in the layout) in order not to dirty user dictionary.

when user types coccus, the software suggests:

[image]

when user types »galanth«, literal matches come first:

[image]

when user types »calanth«, again literal matches come first:

[image]

What you see in the drop down list is `Epithet.toString`.  Clicking on a hint only copies `Epithet.epithet`.